# What is the complement of an event in a sigma algebra?

Tags: measure-theory, sigma-algebra

Consider $\Omega=\{1,2,...,6\}$ and $F=\left\{\{1\},\{3\},\{5\}\right\}$. Let $A={1}$. If $F$ is to be a sigma algebra, then necessarily  $A^c \in F$.  What is $A^c$?

Comment: $A$ is a number and not an event. The event you are thinking about is the _set_ ${1}$; there is a difference between the number and a set whose sole member is the number. Furthermore $F$ is not a sigma algebra; finite sigma algebras have $2^n$ events in them for some positive integer $n$.

Comment: Thank you—so if A were {1}, $A^c$ would be {{2},..,{6} }? Hence F not a sigma algebra because it doesn’t contain $A^c$?

Comment: No, you are still confused between the number 1 and the event $\{1\}$.  The complement of the event $\{1\}$ is the set of all elements in $\Omega$ that _do not_ being to the set $\{1\}$.  This complement is the set $\{2,3,4,5,6\}$ and not the set $\big\{\{1\}, \{2\}, \ldots.\{6\}\big\}$ the way you write it.  The former is a set of five numbers and is a subset of $\Omega$ as the complement must be, the latter is a set whose members are themselves sets and is not a subset of $\Omega$.  Notation is important for understanding the issue.

Comment: My original remark had an unfortunate typo in it. The beginning of the second sentence should read "the event you are thinking of is the set $\{1\}$; ...."

Comment: @DilipSarwate bracket inside the dollar sign?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ on a set $\Omega$ is set containing subsets of $\Omega$ that satisfies the following conditions:

1. $\Omega$ is in $\Sigma$
2. $\Sigma$ is closed under complementation
3. $\Sigma$ is closed under countable unions

You're asking about condition 2, which means: if set $A$ is in $\Sigma$ then so is its complement $A^C$. Here, $A^C$ is the set of all elements in $\Omega$ that are not in $A$:

$$A^C = \{x \in \Omega \mid x \notin A\}$$

As Dilip Sarwate pointed out, the example $A=1$ in your question isn't a valid event because it's not a set. But, let's suppose $A=\{1\}$ instead, as in your comment. Then $A^C = \{2, \dots, 6\}$, which is not in $F$. This violates condition 2, implying that $F$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$. $F$ doesn't satisfy conditions 1 or 3 either.

Comment: I take it $\Sigma$={{},{1},{2,3,4,5,6}} does not violate 2, but violates 1? But $\Sigma$={{},{1},{1,2,3,4,5,6},{2,3,4,5,6}} does not violate either 1 or 2?

Comment: The first example in your comment clearly violates 1. It violates 2 because the complement of the empty set is $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, which is not in $\Sigma$. Similarly, it also violates 3 because $\{1\} \cup \{2,3,4,5,6\} = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\} \notin \Sigma$. The second example satisfies all three conditions.